# Filter out articles published internally using knowledge:articleList

Tags: visualforce, knowledge

I am trying to get a list of only the articles available in our customer portal or public kb but I dont see how to filter by channel using "knowledge:articleList".

Is this possible or will I need to create a custom search using SOQL/SOSL?

Thanks!

Comment: I fear this will be possible through custom SOQL only .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently is not possible and it can be done only through SOQL/SOSL.

Answer (score 1):

Using KnowledgeArticleViewStat , we can fetch articles based on the channels.

SELECT Id, NormalizedScore, Parent.Id 
FROM KnowledgeArticleViewStat where Channel = 'App' 
ORDER BY NormalizedScore

Please refer-
https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleviewstat.htm